# How to determine height of parent div and set for child div?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to build a 'block quote' box for a website and having a hard time setting up the quotation marks around the edges, the text keeps wrapping around them as I can't get them to have the correct height. They should be in line with the text and cause the entry-content text to indent on the entire paragraph.

I've put the quotation marks inside their own divs and have set their height/width accordingly but I can't seem to dynamically determine the height of the div that the actual quote text is in.

I suspect this is because the parent div doesn't have a specific height due to it's dynamic nature but I'm not entirely sure how to go about setting a height for it that is dynamic.

An example of the page is here:

```
http://192.241.203.146/kim-dotcom-launches-mega-co-nz/
```

But an example of what I'm *actually* trying to do can be seen in this image:
[image]

The code that draws the div is:

```
 <div class="span8">
    <div class="quotation qopen">“</div>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>Schlitz magna whatever, aesthetic aliqua odio duis yr lomo american apparel 3 wolf moon meggings ullamco next level Truffaut. Ullamco ennui cillum, scenester plaid next level do bitters twee american apparel enim four loko. Proident eu cornhole, biodiesel umami bespoke velit est do jean shorts literally quis ut stumptown. Polaroid kitsch squid jean shorts, aliqua you probably haven&#8217;t heard of them qui beard sint id odio tofu veniam Schlitz sartorial. Disrupt placeat bicycle rights tousled letterpress. Mustache sartorial +1, vero next level squid non american apparel. Messenger bag Marfa hoodie anim you probably haven&#8217;t heard of them selvage, ugh gentrify accusamus PBR wayfarers Wes Anderson occupy.</p>
        <div class="quotation qclose">”</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .quotation
 {
font-size:4.0em;
font-weight:600;
width:30px;
height:100%;
 }

 .qopen
{
float:left;
width:30px;
position: relative;
}

.qclose
{
float:right;
}

.entry-content { 
font-size:1.0em;
font-family: Agilis;
line-height:150%;
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated greatly. I've been stuck on this for a few days and am still learning - I'm sure it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

You musn't specify the height of an element. You must leave that the browser calculates for you.

See this example: [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PgmTM/1/)

Besides, you must put this CSS property:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

**EDIT:** By the way, to do the quotation marks, you can use pseudo-elements:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="quote">Schlitz magna whatever [...]</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
    content:'"';
    position: absolute;
    font: 600 4em "Agilis", sans-serif;
}

.container:before {
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
}

.container:after {
    bottom: -15px;
    right: 0;
}
```

I've updated the Jsfiddle.

Leo!

Answer (score -1):

Alright, this wasn't as tricky as I thought but took jQuery to answer the question. I found that I needed to dynamically find the height of the div after the dynamic content had loaded into it.

The code I used was:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".qopen").height( $(".entry-content").height() );
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think that your problem is about the quotation marks, not? Well, you don't need Jquery to find the height of the `div` element, just use pseudo-elements, like in my example.

Comment: Yeah, I am just messing around with your code now. It seems like a better solution. Will get back to you once tested.